# Show that $ (\forall x)(A \lor B) \rightarrow A \lor (\forall x)B $ is, in general, NOT a theorem.

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

**Show that** $$ (\forall x)(A \lor B) \rightarrow A \lor (\forall x)B $$ is, in general, **NOT** a theorem.

---

**My answer:**

First, I got the abstraction of the formula which is $ p \rightarrow A \lor q$ then I did a truth table for the abstraction. The truth table show one instance that is false. So the abstraction is not a tautology. Therefore the original formula $(\forall x)(A \lor B) \rightarrow A \lor (\forall x)B$ is also not a tautology.

> $ \not\vDash_{taut} (\forall x)(A \lor B) \rightarrow A \lor (\forall x)B$

By the contrapositive of *Completeness*.

> $ \not\vdash (\forall x)(A \lor B) \rightarrow A \lor (\forall x)B$

---

**Is my answer correct ?**

The original question was "*In particular, find specific wffs $A$ and $B$ such that the above conditional is not a theorem.*" So also I need to know how can I do that ?

I use **Mathematical Logic** by **George Tourlakis**.

Answer (score 3):

1. Predicate logic (quantificational logic) is an extension of propositional logic: there are predicate logic theorems that aren't propositional logic theorems, i.e. which aren't tautologies. Example: $\forall x(A \land B) \to (\forall xA \land \forall xB)$ is a predicate logic theorem, but obviously not a tautology. *So showing a predicate logic wff is not a tautology does not show it is not a predicate logic theorem*.  Hence the reasoning suggested in the question is invalid.
2. Take the domain of quantification to be numbers, let $A$ be $Even(x)$, $B$ mean $Odd(x)$ is odd.  Then $\forall x(A \lor B)$ is true: but there are assignments on which $A \lor \forall xB$ is false -- suppose we assign $x$ the number 3, then both disjuncts are false. So, being falsifiable, by completeness, $(\forall x)(A \lor B) \rightarrow A \lor (\forall x)B$ isn't in general a theorem.
3. Question: what happens if we insist that $A$ does not contain $x$ free?

Answer (score 1):

In the above answer Peter Smith has shown why, in general : $(∀x)(A \lor B) → A \lor (∀x)B$ is **not** *valid* and thus (by *Completeness*) not a theorem.

We will prove the "special case" with the proviso : $x$ not *free* in $A$.

---

We will "mimick" the proof [see **6.4,1 Theorem**, page 172] of :

> $\vdash (\forall x)(A \rightarrow B) \rightarrow (A \rightarrow (\forall x)B)$, provided $x$ is not free in $A$.

We will use :

**2.4.4 Theorem. (Double Negation)** [page 67] : $\vdash \lnot \lnot A \equiv A$

and

**2.4.11 Theorem** [page 70] : $\vdash A \rightarrow B \equiv \lnot A \lor B$

to derive :

> $\vdash A \lor B \equiv \lnot A \rightarrow B$ --- **(*)**

---

*Proof* :

*1)* $(∀x)(A \lor B)$ --- assumed

*2)* $A \lor B$ --- from 1) by **6.1.6 Corollary** : $(\forall x)A \vdash A$

*3)* $\lnot A \rightarrow B$ --- from 2) by **(*)**

*4)* $\lnot A$ --- assumed

*5)* $B$ --- from 3) and 4) bt *modus ponens*

*6)* $(\forall x)B$ --- from 5) by **6.1.1 Metatheorem. (Weak Generalization)** : Let $\Gamma \vdash A$ and let moreover $x$ not occur free in any formula found in the set $\Gamma$. Then $\Gamma \vdash (\forall x)A$ as well. Here $\Gamma = \{ (∀x)(A \lor B), \lnot A \}$ and $x$ is not free in $A$; thus, the (meta-)theorem applies.

*7)* $\lnot A \rightarrow (\forall x)B$ --- from 4) and 6) by **2.6.1 Metatheorem. (Deduction Theorem)** : If $\Gamma \cup \{ A \} \vdash B$, then also $\Gamma \vdash A \rightarrow B$.

*8)* $A \lor (\forall x)B$ --- from 7) applying **(*)** again

*9)* $(∀x)(A \lor B) \rightarrow A \lor (\forall x)B$ --- from 8) by **Deduction Theorem** again.

Thus, we have proved :

> > $(∀x)(A \lor B) \rightarrow A \lor (\forall x)B$, provided that $x$ is not free in $A$.